# Android weekly event not being set for all the days

Tags: java, android, calendar, android-calendar, rrule

I have searched extensively on SO and various forums and I can't figure this one out. I'm generating a reccuring event in Android calendar. Sometimes it works flawlessly and sometimes it sets it only for the upcoming 4-5 weeks and then stops. What precisely am I doing wrong here?

This is my function that adds an event in the calendar

```
private void addToCalendar(int DAY_WEEK, String TITLE, String DESC, String LOC, int hour_s, int min_s, int hour_e, int min_e) {

        Uri uri = Calendars.CONTENT_URI;
        String[] projection = new String[]{
                Calendars._ID,
                Calendars.ACCOUNT_NAME,
                Calendars.CALENDAR_DISPLAY_NAME,
                Calendars.NAME,
                Calendars.CALENDAR_COLOR
        };

        // Construct event details
        long startMillis = 0;
        long endMillis = 0;
        int year = Calendar.getInstance().get(Calendar.YEAR);
        int month = Calendar.getInstance().get(Calendar.MONTH);

        Calendar now = Calendar.getInstance();

        int day = now.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK);
        int daym = now.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
        int start_day = 0;

        if (day != DAY_WEEK) {
            start_day = daym - (day - DAY_WEEK);
            //Toast.makeText(this, Integer.toString(start_day), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        } else {
            start_day = daym;
        }


        Calendar beginTime = Calendar.getInstance();
        beginTime.set(year, month, start_day, hour_s, min_s);
        startMillis = beginTime.getTimeInMillis();
        Calendar endTime = Calendar.getInstance();
        endTime.set(year, month, start_day, hour_e, min_e);
        endMillis = endTime.getTimeInMillis();

        Calendar endRRule = Calendar.getInstance();
        endRRule.add(Calendar.MONTH, 3);
        long endRRuleMillis = endRRule.getTimeInMillis();

        // Insert Event
        ContentResolver cr = getContentResolver();
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        TimeZone timeZone = TimeZone.getDefault();
        values.put(Events.DTSTART, startMillis);
        values.put(Events.DTEND, endMillis);
        values.put(Events.EVENT_TIMEZONE, timeZone.getID());

        values.put(Events.RRULE, "FREQ=WEEKLY;");
        values.put(Events.HAS_ALARM, 1);

        values.put(Events.TITLE, TITLE);
        values.put(Events.DESCRIPTION, DESC);
        values.put(Events.EVENT_LOCATION, LOC);
        values.put(Events.CALENDAR_ID, 1);

        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.WRITE_CALENDAR) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.WRITE_CALENDAR}, 101);

        }

        uri = cr.insert(CalendarContract.Events.CONTENT_URI, values);


        // Retrieve ID for new event
        String eventID = uri.getLastPathSegment();



        ContentValues reminders = new ContentValues();
        reminders.put(CalendarContract.Reminders.EVENT_ID, eventID);
        reminders.put(CalendarContract.Reminders.METHOD, CalendarContract.Reminders.METHOD_ALERT);
        reminders.put(CalendarContract.Reminders.MINUTES, 15);

        Uri uri2 = cr.insert(CalendarContract.Reminders.CONTENT_URI, reminders);

    }
```

And I am calling it from another function which I shortened in order to improve code readability

This loop goes through all of the SQL results from the local database

```
while (c.moveToNext()) {
                                Log.d("COURSE NAME", c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("course_name")));
                                final ListModelSchedules sched = new ListModelSchedules();

                                ...

                                if (setDay != 0 && title != null && desc != null && room != null && setStartTime != 0 && setEndTime != 0)
                                {
                                    addToCalendar(setDay, title, desc, room, setStartTime, 0, setEndTime, 0);
                                }
                            }
```

It adds the event correctly, but instead of it being repeaten indefinitely, it sometimes stops after 4-5 weeks. What am I doing wrong here? If I set RRule's UNTIL=timestamp, it breaks and adds nothing to the calendar. Any help would be appreciated.

EDIT: I just noticed that it actually adds all those events for all of the days. But it shows after you manually select a refresh option inside the calendar app. Is this something that can be solved or is it just the way calendar app is designed?